# Permutations of $\{1,\ldots,2pq\}$ modulo $2pq$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, permutations, reduced-residue-system

I am proposing here a variant of [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1897939/invariance-of-residues-modulo-p/1898015#1898015).

Let $p$ and $q$ be distinct odd primes. Is it true that there exists a permutation $\sigma$ of $\{1,\ldots,2pq\}\times \{1,2\}$ such that
$$
\{\sigma(1,x),\ldots,(2pq)\sigma(2pq,x)\}=\{1,\ldots,2pq\}
$$
modulo $2pq$ for each $x \in \{1,2\}$?

[I think the answer is affirmative, as in the other case]

---

The question is related to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1897148/existence-of-a-prime-with-some-additional-properties?noredirect=1&lq=1). In particular, it follows that the answer is affirmative if $p=3$ and $q=5$.